# How to add a JavaScript callback for the 'Agile Uploader' version 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

On the web page for the Agile Uploader plug-in, where he writes about the release of version 3, its developer writes:

*"The JavaScript callbacks are no more. Instead, there's more of an "event" system. This leaves you to define one event handler function should you like to build your own JavaScript to work with Agile Uploader."*

Needless to say, having a callback function is very important. However, I don't really understand what he means by "defining one event handler function...".
In short, I need a callback function but I don't understand how to add one with version 3 of this plug-in. How do I do it?

Please help

Comment: What I understand from this is that you have to attach a handler function (your supposed callback) to an event. Makes me think of an eventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Included with Agile Uploader 3.0 is a javascript file called **agile-uploader-3.0.js**

*(jQuery is also required if using this method.)*

The file has the core functionality implemented and right at the top is a ready and working example of the event handler function. The definition starts as:

```
$.fn.agileUploaderEvent = function(event) {....
```

To initialise Agile Uploader, you will call the .agileUploader() method on the div element you want to use. In that method you get to set options.

You can set the `js_event_handler:` option (which is a child option of `flashVars:`) to the name of your own function instead of using the default, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image-uploader').agileUploader({
        flashVars: {
            js_event_handler: '$.fn.myUploadEventHandler',    // <-- HERE!
            file_limit: 10,
            maxFileMessage: 'The maximum number of files you can upload has been reached.',
            ... etc
        },
        flashSrc: '.../your-path-to-the-swf-file/agile-uploader.swf',
        ... etc
     });
```

Now define the function. You can call the existing agileUploaderEvent() function to make things easier if you want to, and then just do extra stuff as you need to afterwards, e.g.:

```
     $.fn.myUploadEventHandler = function (event) {

         // First call the default event handler (optional, you could completely rewrite)
         $.fn.agileUploaderEvent(event); 

         // Now handle the events we want to 
         switch (event.type) {
             case 'progress':
                 $.fn.myExtraProgressHandler(event.file);  // Call my custom function (handler)
                 break;
             case 'file_already_attached':
                 console.log('The same file was already attached.'); // Do something useful?
                 break;
         };
     };

     $.fn.myExtraProgressHandler = function (file) {
         if (file.percentEncoded >= 100) {
             console.log('File progress reached 100%');  // Just an example...
             $("#file-attached").show();   // Do whatever we need to when progress >= 100%
         }
     };
```

This example uses jQuery, but if you're planning on 'going it alone' the same principle applies.